# display data into recycler view using mutiple api request and one adapter

Tags: java, android, api, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm using `RecyclerView` to display some data from an API response using one adapter
but i want to display data from more then one API response (so i need to  make more then one get request)
this is my adapter :

```
private Context Context1;
private List<TraitementTicketModel> followuplist;

public FollowupAdapter(Context mContext, List<TraitementTicketModel> followuplist) {
    this.Context1 = mContext;
    this.followuplist = followuplist;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(Context1);
    v=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.followupitem,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.users_id.setText(followuplist.get(position).getUsers_id());
    holder.date.setText(followuplist.get(position).getDate());
    holder.titre.setText(followuplist.get(position).getTitre());
    holder.content.setText(html2text(followuplist.get(position).getContent()));

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return followuplist.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView users_id;
    TextView date;
    TextView content;
    TextView titre;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        users_id=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_id_followup);
        date =itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_followup);
        content=itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenu_followup);
        titre=itemView.findViewById(R.id.titre_followup);
    }
}
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.parse(html).text()).text();
}
```

and this is the code to display the data into the `recyclerview`

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("tokenPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sestoken = sp.getString("token", "");


    SharedPreferences sp1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("idPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String id = sp1.getString("id", "");


    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
    final Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<List<TraitementTicketModel>> call = api.getfollowup(id, sestoken);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TraitementTicketModel>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TraitementTicketModel>> call, Response<List<TraitementTicketModel>> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something is wrong !! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: something is wrong");
                
            }

            List<TraitementTicketModel> followups = response.body();

            for (TraitementTicketModel followup : followups) {
                followuplist.add(followup);
            }

            followuplist.add(firstfollowup());
            PutDataIntoRecyclerView(followuplist);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TraitementTicketModel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


    private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<TraitementTicketModel> followuplist) {
    FollowupAdapter adapter =new FollowupAdapter(this,followuplist);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

so is it possible to display data into  one `recylerview` using one adapter and more then one API request .

**Edit :**

this is the TraitementTicketModel class :

```
public class TraitementTicketModel {

private String users_id;
private String date;
private String content;
private String titre;


public TraitementTicketModel(String users_id, String date, String content, String titre) {
    this.users_id = users_id;
    this.date = date;
    this.content = content;
    this.titre = titre;
}

public String getTitre() {
    return titre;
}

public String getUsers_id() { return users_id; }

public String getDate() { return date; }

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
```

}

when i try to sort the list by date  before i put it in the adapter the data doesn't show .

in the adapter class :

```
public List addToList(List<TraitementTicketModel> list) {
    this.followuplist.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    Collections.sort(followuplist, new Comparator<TraitementTicketModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TraitementTicketModel o1, TraitementTicketModel o2) {
            return o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate());
        }
    });

    return this.followuplist;
}
```

in the main activity :

```
 private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<TraitementTicketModel> followuplist) {

   Sort(followuplist);

    if (adapter == null) {
    adapter=new FollowupAdapter(this,followuplist);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else {
        adapter=new FollowupAdapter(this,adapter.addToList(followuplist));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
private List Sort (List<TraitementTicketModel> datalist){

    Collections.sort(datalist, new Comparator<TraitementTicketModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TraitementTicketModel o1, TraitementTicketModel o2) {
            return o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate());
        }
    });

return datalist;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so is it possible to display data into one recylerview using one adapter and more then one api request

Yes it's possible if all API responses have the same data scheme as the adapter list.

You can add a method in the adapter that accumulates the current list:

```
public addToList(List<TraitementTicketModel> list) {
    this.followuplist.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then make the adapter as a class field, to only be instantiated for the first response, and reuse it in further responses:

```
FollowupAdapter mAdapter;
```

Then if the adapter not instantiated, instantiate it with the initial list, otherwise accumulate the list:

```
private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<TraitementTicketModel> followuplist) {
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new FollowupAdapter(this, followuplist);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } else {
        mAdapter.addToList(followuplist);
    }
     
}
```

Comment: it actualy works but when i try to sort the list t tried to sort the list before i'm put it in the adapter the data doesn't show do you have an idea about that

Comment: @LaroussiAziz if the list exists, then sorting it won't be the reason of not displaying it unless there is an issue on the sorting algorithm or synchronization issue.. I encourage you to open a new question with the full detail so someone could offer a help.. Good luck in it.

Comment: ok  i will do that appreciate it but idk the problem exactly because i used the same sorting method in other class on an other list and it works fine  but in this merged list it doesn't work .

Comment: So, could be something else. Feel free to drop me a comment when you open the question, so that I could understand it well

Comment: already edited this question for more informations

Comment: Please let me have a look if I can find something

Comment: @LaroussiAziz I think `return this.followuplist;` gets called before the comparison is over